# Static type checking in Groovy-Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Is there any way to make Groovy static type safety check other than placing `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked` before class? It works but I find it really pain to place it for every class there. I also find from Eclipse, `context menu (on package tree view) -> Groovy Type Checking -> Type check` but it seems to not take any effect after I choose it.

I would like to have some option which:

1. Works for every *.groovy file in entire project
2. Do not require to place some boiler plate code in every file

So frankly speaking it should work like in Java.

Comment: Not sure it helps but does the "Static compilation by default" section [at the end of this page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Advanced+compiler+configuration) help?

Comment: @tim_yates well the trick with dsl config actaully works, thanks.

Comment: The link is now dead, here's a mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20150313071944/http://groovy.codehaus.org/Advanced+compiler+configuration